# Association for table less model

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I've been trying to implement the association at FrontEnd but as currently the application in not having any database directly connected with the website, so as a result we can not use the ActiveRecord and only using the ActiveModel for supporting the validations and core features of a Model. Now as we need to use the nested attributes which we are going to send along with an object, the addresses which are associated with the User, so for this we need to first define the association on the corresponding model. But after defining the association it is throwing exception of undefined method "has_many" on User model. I'm currently searching the way to implement it in our website and implement the logic of nested attributes.
It would be great if you can suggest me anything related to this or if you have met with such issue in the past.
I've also tried the approach using the gem https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless but not working for me. Also I've added a tableless.rb

tableless.rb

```
class Tableless < ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new( name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null )
  end

  def self.columns()
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.columns_hash
    h = {}
    for c in self.columns
    h[c.name] = c
    end
    return h
  end

  def self.column_defaults
    Hash[self.columns.map{ |col|
    [col.name, col.default]
    }]
  end
  def self.descends_from_active_record?
    return true
  end
  def persisted?
    return false
  end
# override the save method to prevent exceptions
end
```

But getting the following exception Exception:

Console Error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:92:in `get_primary_key'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:77:in `reset_primary_key'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:65:in `primary_key'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:79:in `reset_primary_key'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:65:in `primary_key'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:32:in `write_attribute'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:70:in `write_attribute'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:19:in `__temp__9646='
    from /home/cis/API_OTGJ/Tableless/app/models/book.rb:13:in `block in initialize'
    from /home/cis/API_OTGJ/Tableless/app/models/book.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/cis/API_OTGJ/Tableless/app/models/book.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from (irb):19
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@website/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is the problem when you use https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to call the method

```
has_no_table
```

On your model, as per https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless#usage. In their example:

```
class ContactMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table
  column :name, :string
  column :email, :string
  validates_presence_of :name, :email
end
```

Hope this helps. =)